# Are the WCF Endpoints kept in the app.config or the web.config?

Tags: wcf

When I create a WCF Service Library, an app.config is generated for me where I put the end points.  Then if I create a website and reference the WCF Service Library, it creates a web.config file where I can specify the end points.  Do I put the end points in the app.config or web.config or do they have to be in both?

Comment: Web.config if you're hosting the services in IIS, app.config if you're self hosting...

Comment: So Can I just delete the app.config?

Comment: Yes... it seems to be a bit of a quirk that visual studio introduces them for you sometimes....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, it's `Web.config` if you're hosting the services in IIS, `app.config` if you're self hosting.  So it sounds like you want to put them in the `web.config`.

[Full details can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733932.aspx) where MSDN says:

> When configuring a service in Visual
>   Studio, use either a Web.config file
>   or an App.config file to specify the
>   settings. The choice of the
>   configuration file name is determined
>   by the hosting environment you choose
>   for the service. **If you are using IIS
>   to host your service, use a Web.config**
>   file. If you are using **any other
>   hosting environment, use an App.config**
>   file.
>
> In Visual Studio, the file named
>   App.config is used to create the final
>   configuration file. The final name
>   actually used for the configuration
>   depends on the assembly name. For
>   example, an assembly named
>   "Cohowinery.exe" has a final
>   configuration file name of
>   "Cohowinery.exe.config". However, you
>   only need to modify the App.config
>   file. Changes made to that file are
>   automatically made to the final
>   application configuration file at
>   compile time.